# How to create a directive with a dynamic template in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I create a directive with a dynamic template?

```js
'use strict';

app.directive('ngFormField', function($compile) {
return {
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        label: '@'
    },
    template: '<label for="user_email">{{label}}</label>',
    // append
    replace: true,
    // attribute restriction
    restrict: 'E',
    // linking method
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
        switch (attrs['type']) {
            case "text":
                // append input field to "template"
            case "select":
                // append select dropdown to "template"
        }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<ng-form-field label="First Name" type="text"></ng-form-field>
```

This is what I have right now, and it is displaying the label correctly. However, I'm not sure on how to append additional HTML to the template. Or combining 2 templates into 1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Had a similar need. `$compile` does the job. (Not completely sure if this is "THE" way to do it, still working my way through angular)

http://jsbin.com/ebuhuv/7/edit - my exploration test.

One thing to note (per my example), one of my requirements was that the template would change based on a `type` attribute once you clicked save, and the templates were very different. So though, you get the data binding, if need a new template in there, you will have to recompile.

Comment: It doesn't seem your example is working correctly. Could you follow up?

Comment: Edit: Got it working, looks like it was bootstrap.

Updated link: http://jsbin.com/wikocaru/2/edit

Comment: Answers should include complete examples and code, not links which end up being broken links later on.

Comment: Would be nice see at little snippet of code in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 32):

i've used the $templateCache to accomplish something similar. i put several ng-templates in a single html file, which i reference using the directive's templateUrl. that ensures the html is available to the template cache. then i can simply select by id to get the ng-template i want.

template.html:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id=“foo”>
foo
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id=“bar”>
bar
</script>
```

directive:

```
myapp.directive(‘foobardirective’, ['$compile', '$templateCache', function ($compile, $templateCache) {

    var getTemplate = function(data) {
        // use data to determine which template to use
        var templateid = 'foo';
        var template = $templateCache.get(templateid);
        return template;
    }

    return {
        templateUrl: 'views/partials/template.html',
        scope: {data: '='},
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            var template = getTemplate(scope.data);

            element.html(template);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Nice move, Zim! Just a slight simplification: $templateCache is available inside the link function so you don't really need the getTemplate function

Comment: @zim But how would you pass id dynamically?

Comment: +1 for `$compile(element.contents())`. Was going crazy because I didn't know about that `.contents()` ìn `$compile`. (infinite loop calling my directive, of course)

Comment: @zim As stated by @IcanDivideBy0, your solution does not work if we use `replace: true` in the directive. By any chance, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Devner, no i don't have a solution for `replace: true`.

Comment: @JannieT, i have a separate `getTemplate()` function just to keep the link function clean. i could inline it, yes, but if it takes a lot of code to parse the data and determine which template to use, it can obscure the important last 2 lines of the link function. And i'm a fan of small, single function methods anyway.

Comment: And this might break if you have transcluded contents which you don't want to lose.

Answer (score 8):

You should move your switch into the template by using the '[ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)' directive:

```
module.directive('testForm', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controllerAs: 'form',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            console.log("Form controller initialization");
            var self = this;
            this.fields = {};
            this.addField = function(field) {
                console.log("New field: ", field);
                self.fields[field.name] = field;
            };
        }
    }
});

module.directive('formField', function () {
    return {
        require: "^testForm",
        template:
            '<div ng-switch="field.fieldType">' +
            '    <span>{{title}}:</span>' +
            '    <input' +
            '        ng-switch-when="text"' +
            '        name="{{field.name}}"' +
            '        type="text"' +
            '        ng-model="field.value"' +
            '    />' +
            '    <select' +
            '        ng-switch-when="select"' +
            '        name="{{field.name}}"' +
            '        ng-model="field.value"' +
            '        ng-options="option for option in options">' +
            '        <option value=""></option>' +
            '    </select>' +
            '</div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            fieldType: "@",
            title: "@",
            name: "@",
            value: "@",
            options: "=",
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, form) {
            $scope.field = $scope;
            form.addField($scope);
        }
    };
});
```

It can be use like this:

```
<test-form>
    <div>
        User '{{!form.fields.email.value}}' will be a {{!form.fields.role.value}}
    </div>
    <form-field title="Email" name="email" field-type="text" value="me@example.com"></form-field>
    <form-field title="Role" name="role" field-type="select" options="['Cook', 'Eater']"></form-field>
    <form-field title="Sex" name="sex" field-type="select" options="['Awesome', 'So-so', 'awful']"></form-field>
</test-form>
```

Answer (score 5):

One way is using a template function in your directive:

```
...
template: function(tElem, tAttrs){
    return '<div ng-include="' + tAttrs.template + '" />';
}
...
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use AngularJs Directive with dynamic template, you can use those answers,But here is more **professional** and **legal** syntax of it.**You can use templateUrl not only with single value.You can use it as a function,which returns a value as url**.That function has some arguments,which you can use.

http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/angularjs/dynamically-change-template-url-in-angularjs-directives.html

Comment: This doesn't allow for dynamically changing the contents when some data changes. For example I was a data-type attribute to dictate the template to be used - then when the user switches type, I need a different template.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to deal with this problem. Below is the link :

https://github.com/nakosung/ng-dynamic-template-example

with the specific file being:

https://github.com/nakosung/ng-dynamic-template-example/blob/master/src/main.coffee

`dynamicTemplate` directive hosts dynamic template which is passed within scope and hosted element acts like other native angular elements.

```
scope.template = '< div ng-controller="SomeUberCtrl">rocks< /div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been in the same situation, my **complete solution** has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942419/angularjs-create-a-directive-that-adds-a-sibling-element/33757833#33757833)

Basically I load a template in the directive in this way

```
var tpl = '' + 
    <div ng-if="maxLength" 
        ng-include="\'length.tpl.html\'">
    </div>' +
    '<div ng-if="required" 
        ng-include="\'required.tpl.html\'">
    </div>';
```

then according to the value of `maxLength` and `required` I can dynamically load one of the 2 templates, only one of them at a time is shown if necessary.

I heope it helps.