# dynamic template to directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I need to decide the template based on the date. I saw a good [example](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/). 
But in that example the templates are so simple that he could used strings. In my case I want use php to produce the templates, so I used it this way:

```
eng.directive('vis', function ($compile) {
var getTemplate = function(ir) {
    var k = (ir.visits.last && parseInt(ir.visits.last.done))?'V':'E';
    var s = (ir.data.kind == 0)?'H':'V';
    return s+k+'T';
}

var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('ir',function(){
        if (!scope.ir) return;
        element.html(jQuery('#'+getTemplate(scope.ir)).html()).show();
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    })
}
return {
    restrict: "E",
    rep1ace: true,
    link: linker
};});
```

and the templates are:

```
<div id=HVT style="display:none">
    <p>horizontal view template</p>
</div>
<div id=HET style="display:none">
    <p>horizontal {{1+5}} Edit template</p>
</div>
<div id=VVT style="display:none">
    <p>vertical view template</p>
</div>
<div id=VET style="display:none">
    <p>vertical Edit template</p>
</div>
```

I am sure there is a smarter way. 
is it better to use templateUrl ? could somebody tell me how to use it in my case?

Edit: there is a problem. the template does not see the scope

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is also possible for creating dynamic templates in AngularJS:
In your directive use:

```
template : '<div ng-include="getTemplateUrl()"></div>'
```

Now your controller may decide which template to use:

```
$scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
  return '/template/angular/search';
};
```

Because you have access to your scope parameters, you could also do:

```
$scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
  return '/template/angular/search/' + $scope.query;
};
```

So your server could create a dynamic template for you.

Comment: template & templateUrl can take a function like: `function(el,attrs){ return '/tmpls/' + attrs.template; }`

Comment: I tried above method, its working fine for me now even i have control over navigation,only problem is if i have dynamic state(state('manualTest/:testName', ) and am coming back to dynamic state page, ng-init is getting called twice

Answer (score 3):

I find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862315/angularjs-directive-template-dynamic)

in this example http://jsbin.com/ebuhuv/7/edit

find this code:

```
app.directive("pageComponent", function($compile) {
    var template_for = function(type) {
        return type+"\\.html";
    };
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        // transclude: true,
        scope: true,
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var tmpl = template_for(scope.component.type);
                element.html($("#"+tmpl).html()).show();
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            };
        }
    };});
```

Answer (score 2):

With Angular, you don't need to use `id`s.  Also, instead of `display:none` you can use `ng-show`:

```
<div ng-show="HVT">
    <p>horizontal view template</p>
</div>
<div ng-show="HET">
    <p>horizontal {{1+5}} Edit template</p>
</div>
...
```

Your $watch callback (which you can define on a controller or in a directive) can then simply modify the appropriate scope property:

```
var getTemplate = function (ir) {
    var k = (ir.visits.last && parseInt(ir.visits.last.done)) ? 'V' : 'E';
    var s = (ir.data.kind == 0) ? 'H' : 'V';
    return s + k + 'T';
}
$scope.$watch('ir', function () {
    if (!$scope.ir) return;
    // hide all, then show the one we want
    $scope.HVT = false;
    $scope.HET = false;
    $scope.VVT = false;
    $scope.VET = false;
    $scope[getTemplate($scope.ir)] = true;
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/DmZeV/).  The fiddle has the above code in a controller, since I have no idea where you might be using the directive.  The fiddle also just hardcodes "VET", since I don't know what `ir` looks like.