# AngularJS - Create a directive that adds a sibling element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a `my-validate` directive that looks something like this

```
<input my-validate="customValidation" ng-model="model" />
```

What I want to do is to attach a sybling element to the directive like this

Error template:

```
<ul class"errors">
   <li ng-repeat="for error in errors">{{error}} not valid</li>
</ul>
```

`errors` is defined in the scope of the directive.

I've added the error template in the `compile` function, but the problem I have is that the `scope` in the link function is not the same as the attached template.

Here is a plunker to illustrate the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/ghdtdYruQaaO0Yxxlrt1?p=preview

'world' is seen in the directive template, but not on the added element :S.

Comment: The plunker link is not related to the question. I assume you have overwritten it? Please fix this.

Answer (score 6):

That's because your div "2 hello" is outside the container where your scope is visible.
you can use `element.append()` instead of `element.after()` to have the scope available.

#### Directive

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);


app.directive('myValidate', function($compile) {
      return {
        template: '<span>1. Hello {{world}}  my scope is {{$id}} (parent: {{$parent.$id}})<span/>',
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        compile: function (element) {

          element.append('<div>2. Hello {{ world }}, my scope is {{$id}} (parent: {{$parent.$id}})</div>');

          return function(scope) {
            scope.world = 'World';
            //$compile()(scope);
          };
        }
      };
});
```

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input my-validate="" />
  </body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/dU3holBCePKe0ZAwQKh1?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, the problem is I need it to be a sibling, not a child element.

Comment: I suggest you to wrap it with div ( somewhat `'<div class='validatedInput'> <input ng-model="world" /> </div>'` ) and use `element.append`

Comment: Te problem now is that the original attributes will be in the div and not in the input: http://plnkr.co/edit/23iwRQsdB6MxMU16NlHP?p=preview

Comment: @martinpaulucci, take a look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/ohDtJqBCrmB8vhygrVQw?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I was reading and checking the example because I was in the same situation to display validation messages but **under** the input field and the message can change according to what kind of validation is required.

So I came up with this solution

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, CONSTANTS) {
  $scope.title = "title";
  $scope.CONSTANTS = CONSTANTS;
});

app.constant('CONSTANTS', {
  LENGHT_1: 3,
  LENGHT_2: 4
});

app.directive('dir', function($compile) {
  return {
    scope: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
      scope.maxLength = false;
      scope.required = false;
      scope.max = scope.$eval(attrs['ngMaxlength']);
      var tpl = '<div ng-if="maxLength" ng-include="\'length.tpl.html\'"></div>' +
        '<div ng-if="required" ng-include="\'required.tpl.html\'"></div>';
      var el = $compile(tpl)(scope);
      elem.after(el);

      scope.$watch(attrs['ngModel'], function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {
        if (ngModel.$error !== null && ngModel.$error.maxlength) {
          scope.maxLength = true;
        } else {
          scope.maxLength = false;
        }

        if (ngModel.$error !== null && ngModel.$error.required && ngModel.$dirty) {
          scope.required = true;
        } else {
          scope.required = false;
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="length.tpl.html">
    max length {{max}}
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="required.tpl.html">
    required
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ctrl">
  <h1>Input Validation</h1> {{title}}
  <br><br>
  <form name="form" novalidate>
    <input dir name="input_one" ng-model="bar" ng-maxlength="CONSTANTS.LENGHT_1" required>
    <br>
    input one: {{form.input_one.$error}}
    <br>
    <br>
    <input dir name="input_two" ng-model="foo" ng-maxlength="CONSTANTS.LENGHT_2">
  </form>
  <br>
  input two: {{form.input_two.$error}}
</body>

</html>
```

[On Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/17w6tWzvzRvUIUQNVrSr)

Hope it helps.

Comment: This definitely works, and that's nice, but it would be great to be able to specify a single template as a whole for the whole collection of siblings, instead of having to rely on JS-side DOM manipulation to append, prepend, or whatever.

Answer (score -2):

I think you're on the right track by using the form errors to toggle display. That's exactly how it's recommended in the standard Angular documentation.

If you'd like to show multiple errors for a single input, however, and possible even control the error messages from there, I'd recommend utilizing a service, such as implemented at http://plnkr.co/edit/iNcNs2ErrOnYf9I7whdu?p=preview.

Right now you can have one message per token, but as many tokens as you want per input. If you want multiple messages per token, just use an array of messages instead of single string value (note, unset does become more complicated with that method).

Hope that helps,
Alex

Comment: This doesn't address the question.