# How to include data/scope from controller in a dynamically added directive?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to include scope with a directive that I add to the dom on a click event in a controller.

Step 1. On a click event, I call a function in my controller that adds a directive like this

```
$scope.addMyDirective = function(e, instanceOfAnObjectPassedInClickEvent){
   $(e.currentTarget).append($compile("<my-directive mydata='instanceOfAnObjectPassedInClickEvent'/>")($scope));

}
   //I'm trying to take the `instanceOfAnObjectPassedInClickEvent` and make it available in the directive through `mydata`
```

The above, part of which I got [from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862315/angularjs-directive-template-dynamic), successfully adds the directive (and the directive has a template that gets added to the dom), however, inside the directive, I'm not able to access any of the scope data `mydata` it says it's `undefined`.

My directive

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){

    return {
       restrict: 'AE',
       scope: {
         mydata: '='
         //also doesn't work if I do mydata: '@'
       },
       template: '<div class="blah">yippee</div>',
       link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {
              console.log(scope) //inspecting scope shows that mydata is undefined
         }
    }
}
```

Update
 I changed the name of `datafromclickedscope` in the OP to make it more clear. In the controller action `addMyDirective` (see above) `instanceOfAnObjectPassedInClickEvent` is an instance of an object passed into the controller method on a click event that I try to pass into the directive as `mydata='instanceOfAnObjectPassedInClickEvent'`. However, even if I change `=` to `@` in the directive and I try to access scope.mydata in the link function of the directive, it just shows a string like this `"instanceOfAnObjectPassedInClickEvent"`, not the actual object data that is available to me in my method that handles the click event

Comment: I'm assuming `datafromclickedscope` is a key that would be used to reference a value on `$scope` ? Like `$scope.hello = "World"; $scope.addMyDirective(event, "hello");`, and you're expecting `"World"` in the directive? Otherwise, if you want to get `"hello"`, your `mydata: '='`  has to be `mydata: '@'`

Comment: @DRobinson. I changed the name of `datafromclickedscope` in the OP to make it more clear. It is an `instanceOfAnObjectPassedInClickEvent` that I wish to pass into the directive. However, even if I change `=` to `@` and I try to access @scope.mydata in the directive, it just shows a string like this `"instanceOfAnObjectPassedInClickEvent"`, not the actual object data that is available to me in my method that handles the click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `mydata='instanceOfAnObjectPassedInClickEvent'` in a template you need `instanceOfAnObjectPassedInClickEvent` to defined in $scope. So before compiling you should assign a variable in $scope. I will rename this variable in code below, so that same names would not confuse you and it would be clear that a formal parameter of a function cannot be visible in a template.

```
$scope.addMyDirective = function(e, instanceOfAnObjectPassedInClickEvent){
   $scope.myEvent = instanceOfAnObjectPassedInClickEvent;
   $(e.currentTarget).append($compile("<my-directive mydata='myEvent'/>")($scope));
}
```

**EDIT:** slightly adapted [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/z3v6jhah/) *not using JQuery* no manipulate DOM

Comment: Thank you it works in that I can access  mydata in the directive as scope.mydata (but I have to run it through JSON.parse(scope.mydata) ] however the template that gets added by my directive is a bit more complex than in the OP, it has an ng-click event I it that's supposed the trigger a function on the controller. However if I click it, it doesn't activate the functionDoes that mean $scope is not being included when I $compile the template?  -not sure if this problem is related to original question or if I should post a different question

Comment: When I click the link to your jsfiiddle it just takes me to login page

Comment: Sorry for the broken link. Fixed

Comment: Yes, that is another question. When you have isolated scope (as in your code) you cannot access anything else from controller besides what you have straightly defined. As an option you can avoid using isolated scope as in this version of [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/z3v6jhah/6/)