# dynamic templates/theming system for Angular app

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a nice dynamic theming system in my angular app.
Basically I have a Wordpress plugin which you pick via a dropdown which theme you want for my Angular app (which is on the same server in a subfolder), and I pass along the theme via a GET param, www.mywebsite.com/myapp/welcome?theme=white_theme, and the angular app in that folder currently will quickly set in the frontcontroller (think I will move this into an app.js resolve for the route so it happens before the controller, right now I just have the resolve setting a default theme):

```
var dynamic_theme = URI.parseQuery(query_string).theme; //url param gotten via URI js library
if(dynamic_theme) {
  $rootScope.theme_name = dynamic_theme;
} else {
  $rootScope.theme_name = 'default';
}
```

and later on in the index.html i include the dynamic theme via ng-href:

```
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/generic.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/generic.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
<link rel="stylesheet" ng-if="theme_name" ng-href="styles/themes/{{theme_name}}/main-theme.css">
```

But I also want the .html templates themselves to be able to be overwritten by our design theme for each theme.
For example, in app.js, to start off this 'questionnaire' app I have this defined:

```
templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
```

and in that file, i have a directive:

That directive uses the template 'views/question.html'
which inside of that file I decide whether to get 'views/templates/radio.tpl.html', 'views/templates/checkbox.tpl.html', 'views/templates/dropdown.tpl.html' based on the question-type passed to the directive.
like so:

```
<div ng-include src="'views/templates/' + currentquestion.question_type + '.tpl.html'"></div>
```

I guess maybe I can pass the theme into the directive (or just have access to the $rootScope) and do something like so:

```
<div ng-include src="'views/templates/' + dynamic_theme + '/' + currentquestion.question_type + '.tpl.html'"></div>
```

I was just curious if that sounds like a plan. or is there a better way to do this (or even a real theming resolver library/setup you can use for Angular that does the same things that I'm trying to achieve manually).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be a number of [different ways to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862315/angularjs-directive-template-dynamic), the most promising looks to be [using `templateUrl` as a function](http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/angularjs/dynamically-change-template-url-in-angularjs-directives.html):

```
  templateUrl: function(elem,attrs){
      return 'views/templates/' + resolveTheme() + 'main.tpl.html';
  },
```

You would have to write `resolveTheme()` yourself, possibly as a global or a service.

### Alternative

Another option, if you can precompile your templates you can use the `$templateCache` and dynamically load the right template pack.  You'd need to make sure this happened before any of the templates were requested as angular will make an HTTP request for any templates that it can't already find.

Here is one way to pre-compile your templates:
https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js

You could then have multiple template packs: `template-theme1.js`, `template-theme2.js`

And either build multiple versions of the app or include these templates after your application code (but before any templates get requested).