# Changing ui-view based on dropdown

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a page that is built of a few partials and I am trying to load on of these based off of what the user chooses from a drop down.

I have a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8RV8Yz?p=preview) set up with what I have so far.

Basically the drop down has options like INV and BTW so I need to load the Ui-view based on that.

```
<div ui-view="name of view e.g. INV"></div>
```

The name of the view should change based on the selected option.

Any Help is greatly appreciated. Also if the is not possible with UI-View what is an alternative to loading these different partials based on the drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of options available to you.

#### Option 1

Use an `ng-switch` to show hide different parts of the page depending on the value of the dropdown. You can then use `ng-include` to include the partials.

```
<div ng-switch="view">
  <div ng-switch-when="INV" ng-include="inv.template.html"></div>
  <div ng-switch-when="OTHER" ng-include="other.template.html"></div>
  <div ng-switch-default ng-include="default.template.html"></div>
</div>
```

This [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/lwS1txfDGyD8SCnRrKFr?p=preview) also details another method (taken from the angularjs docs on [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

#### Option 2

Dynamically change the template, [this blog post](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/.) or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862315/angularjs-directive-template-dynamic) details how to do so.

*edit: You shouldn't use the template function to dynamically change the view.*

Comment: I am pretty new to Angular, would you be willing to give a code example of using a function instead of the string; I see what you mean just not how to implement it. Thank you so much

Comment: @AdamPenn sorry, I was mistaken with assigning a function to the template.

Comment: Thank you so much, I used ng-switch and it worked perfectly. I greatly appreciate your help. I had been hitting my head with this for 2 days now.