# How do I extract DOM elements from an AngularJS service into their own template?

Tags: html, angularjs, dom, angularjs-service

In my AngularJS app, I have a `service` (or more technically, a `provider`) which contains a bunch of logic to insert DOM elements on the `<body>`.

It is quite cumbersome and hard to follow; for example, there are a lot of `.append` calls of one element into another and into another.

I would like to extract all the DOM code from the service into its own template file. The problem is, while I can find [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21144176/1675976) for how to do this with directives, I cannot figure out how this would work with a service.

NOTE that I need this to remain a service (as opposed to a directive) because I need it to overlay the entire screen and be callable from a variety of different controllers.

I've recreated my situation [in a Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/LsV2ALH0NsapXK4OiI8J?p=preview) and below, though the service's DOM logic is obviously simplified and shrunk

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.provider('MyProvider', [function(){
  this.$get = ['$window', function($window){


    return function(){
      
      var bodyElement = angular.element($window.document.body);
      var myNewElement = angular.element('<div class="my-new-element">');
      var someText = angular.element('<p>Here is some text<p>');
      var xButton = angular.element('<button>X</button>');
      xButton.on('click', function(){
        myNewElement.remove();
      });
      myNewElement.append(someText);
      myNewElement.append(xButton);
      bodyElement.append(myNewElement);
    }

  }];
}]);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'MyProvider', function($scope, MyProvider){
  $scope.amount1 = 1234.56;
  $scope.symbol2 = 'USD$';
  $scope.amount2 = '1234.56';
  
  
  $scope.activateService = function(){
    MyProvider();
  }
}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>

  <style>
    .my-new-element {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
      background-color: green;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
    }

    button {
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 15px 0;
      background-color: #bbb;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="">

  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <span>Amount1: {{amount1 | currency:"USD$"}}</span><br/>
    <span>Symbol2: <input ng-model="symbol2"/></span><br/>
    <span>Amount2: <input ng-model="amount2"/></span><br/>

    <button ng-click="activateService()">Activate The Service</button>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like a little app restructuring is in order. A service should be handling data, not complex template logic.

Comment: You should probably have a directive sitting in each of those locations, and your controller passes data to them, which triggers their visibility, repeats, etc.

Comment: @isherwood Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is that you diagram your app using a simple nested box model as a sanity check. It's hard for me to offer specific advice from what I know (and the time I have to give it).

Comment: In the example I posted. My app doesn't have anything especially unique besides this "global" service

Answer (score 0):

You could probably this into both a Directive and a Service.  Say something like:

```
app.service('MyOverlayService', [function(...){}]);
app.directive('myOverlay', ['MyOverlayService', function(os){...}];
```

Where your service contained things like:

- visible [boolean]
- list of objects to display (menu items perhaps?)
- etc

and your directive listened to those things:

- Toggle display/visible based on {{os.visible}}
- Listed all the data on in for example if this is a menu, you'd ng-repeat items in os.menus

You could then put your overlay directive on your highest template, and in each of your controllers inject MyOverlayService and do a:

```
os.setVisible(true); // or os.toggle()
```